# How to change timestamp from MMDDYYYY to YYYYMMDD in CSV files?

Tags: ksh

I have a csv file reading something like:

```
"Name","Payment",...,"DATE"
"Mike","40",...,"12252012"
"Jack","55",...,"01162013"
...
```

The file contain around several thousand such listings. And there are some fields whose values may be 8-digit or longer numbers. One thing is certain: the DATE field is the last column.

How could I change the DATE column in it from MMDDYYYY to YYYYMMDD format?

Better in Korn Shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** If date field is always the last one in a row, you can use:

```
cat file.csv | perl -pe 's/(.*,")(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})"/$1$4$2$3"/'
```

or

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(.*,")(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})"/$1$4$2$3"/' file.csv
```

---

If CSV has only one field with eight or more digits:

With Perl:

```
cat file.csv | perl -pe 's/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/$3$1$2/'
```

or shorter (edit file in place):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$3$1$2/' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But how to deal with the possibility of any other column having exactly 8 digits? There is one criteria, though: the DATE is always the last column.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks the ending quote is lost?

Comment: Sorry for that, now it's okay